# Retrieving LinkedIn company logoV2 (full URL) without using projection

Tags: linkedin-api

I am using the LinkedIn rest API **202306** and I am trying to update to the latest version.

But With the following endpoint:

organizations = https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-lookup-api?view=li-lms-2023-06&tabs=http

I use projection to retrieve the full URL of the company logo.

```php
// Laravel
$json = Http::withToken(...)
   ->get("organizations/$id",['projection' => '(logoV2(original~:playableStreams))')
   ->json();
```

This works in **202306**, but when you upgrade to higher version.

I am getting the following error:

> projection parameter is not allowed for this endpoint.

While reading the documentation, LinkedIn is planning to fully phase out the use of **projection**.

Can anyone suggest an alternative solution for obtaining the complete URL of a company logo?

I have already tried other endpoint for retrieving the original company URL.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api?view=li-lms-2022-11&tabs=http

Answer (score 4):

Classic projections were removed from recent versions of the LinkedIn API in favor of field projection. We found a solution to get the image url using LinkedIn Image API.

You can use `fields=` to filter the request down to the `logoV2.original` field which provides the URN of the image. Next replace `digitalmediaAsset` with `image`. Then using the modified URN you can query the image API to get the download URL. See below:

1. Query `/rest/organizations`

   - https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizations/19205022?fields=logoV2:(original),localizedName,id

```
{
  "localizedName": "Smart Post App, LLC.",
  "logoV2": {
    "original": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C560BAQGBzZXn5Schaw"
  },
  "id": 19205022
}
```

2. Replace `digitalmediaAsset` in the `logoV2.original` with `image`

```
var imageURN = response.logoV2.original;
imageURN = imageURN.Replace("digitalmediaAsset", "image");
imageURN = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(imageURN);
```

3. Call Image API using modified imageURN

   - [https://api.linkedin.com/rest/images/{imageURN}?fields=downloadUrl"](https://api.linkedin.com/rest/images/%7BimageURN%7D?fields=downloadUrl%22)

```
var client = new RestClientWrapper();

var resource = $"https://api.linkedin.com/rest/images/{imageURN}?fields=downloadUrl";
var headers = RestHeaders.GetCommonHeaders(accessToken);
var response = await client.GetAsync<LinkedInImageObject>(resource, headers);

return response?.DownloadUrl;
```

```
{
  "downloadUrl": "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQGBzZXn5Schaw/company-logo_400_400/0/1676652154924?e=1714003200&v=beta&t=-efWsvFC_0d51teSWBLv3YfF8cUMvhe66hH6XUjIseQ"
}
```

*We did have to URL encode the images URL request as the v2 API won't accept `:`.*

[Image API Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/shares/images-api?view=li-lms-2024-01&tabs=http#get-a-single-image)

[Field Projection Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/projections?context=linkedin%2Fcontext)

Comment: just run into this issue today. does that mean it's impossible to get logoV2 using the organizationsLookup endpoint from the latest API?

Comment: Correct, it's not currently possible via organizationsLookup, the solution above does work.