# How we can get actual image URLs from linkedin API in versions after 202307 as projection is deprecated

Tags: linkedin-api

As projection is deprecated in newer versions on Linkedin API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/decoration

so for getting actual URLs and not URNs we can not use projection,

I do not know how to get actual URLs without projection.

projection=(elements(*(logoV2(original~:playableStreams))))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving LinkedIn company logoV2 (full URL) without using projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77357526/retrieving-linkedin-company-logov2-full-url-without-using-projection)

Comment: yes, this way I could do that by reaching out to support. thank you anyway!